# Javascript: how to merge two arrays by univocal key, and based on property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filtering

I have two arrays: one for persons, and one to map user's ratings and valutations to any person.
Simplified, it is something like this:

```
var persons = [
  { id: '1', name: 'alice' },
  { id: '2', name: 'bob' },
  { id: '3', name: 'charlie' },
];   

var usersToPersons = [
  { userId: '1', personId: '1', hide: true },
  { userId: '1', personId: '2', hide: false },
  { userId: '7', personId: '3' },
];
```

I need to extract persons not 'hidden' by current user.
To date I have come up with this (working, but quite dumb) function:

```
function getPersonsForUser(userId) {
  var result = {};
  for (var p = 0; p < persons.length; p++) {
    for (var u = 0; u < usersToPersons.length; u++) {
      if (usersToPersons[u].userId === userId) {
        if (persons[p].id === usersToPersons[u].personId) {
          if (usersToPersons[u].hide === true) {
            console.warn('person', persons[p].name, 'skipped because this user hides it');
            break;
          } else {
            result[persons[p].id] = persons[p];
          }
        } else {
          result[persons[p].id] = persons[p];
        }
      } else {
        result[persons[p].id] = persons[p];
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getPersonsForUser('1'));
```

Result:

```
person alice skipped because this user hides it
{ '2': { id: '2', name: 'bob' },
  '3': { id: '3', name: 'charlie' } }
```

The question is: is there any more fast/smart/slick method to filter persons by user?

Comment: Why your code returns `charlie`? Its corresponding userId is not '1'

Comment: Because I want to hide persons whom have been marked as hidden by user by userId '1'; I want all other persons, even those for which user by userId '1' did not set any flag.

Comment: `{ userId: '7', personId: '3' }`. 7 !== 1

Comment: Yes: `if (usersToPersons[u].userId === userId) {
        ...
       } else {
         result[persons[p].id] = persons[p];
       }` I.e.: I want to hide only persons which a specific user did choose to hide. I want to get all other persons (no matter what other users did choose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: [Array prototype filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
function getVisible(selUserId){
  var visiblePersons = persons.filter(function(v,i,a){
    var isThisPersonVisible = !usersToPersons.filter(function(vv,ii,aa){
      return (vv.personId === v.id && !vv.hide && vv.userId === selUserId || !vv.userId);
    }).length;

    return isThisPersonVisible;
  });

  return visiblePersons;
}
```

you can try it here

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/369upmha/2/)

Hope this helps

Comment: This is nice! Didn't remember about `Array.prototype.filter()`... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With ES6 it would be like this:

```
let getPersonsForUser = (id) => {
  let ids = usersToPersons
      .filter(user => user.userId === id && !user.hide)
      .map(user => user.personId);

  return persons.filter(person => ids.includes(person.id));
};
```

You could do the same in ES5, but it will be a little more verbose.

Comment: No ES6, yet, please... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use underscore library for that:

```js
var persons = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'alice'
}, {
  id: '2',
  name: 'bob'
}, {
  id: '3',
  name: 'charlie'
}, ];

var usersToPersons = [{
  userId: '1',
  personId: '1',
  hide: true
}, {
  userId: '1',
  personId: '2',
  hide: false
}, {
  userId: '7',
  personId: '3'
}, ];

function getPersonsForUser(userId) {
  return _.map(
    _.filter(usersToPersons,
      function(doc) {
        return doc.userId === userId && !doc.hide
      }),
    function(doc) {
      return persons[doc.personId]
    });
}

console.log(getPersonsForUser('1'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is nice, but your code returns only one object ('charlie')... :-(